# VS 2017 asp.net MVC where is owin startup class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, visual-studio-2017

I created a new web application with VS2017, by choosing asp.net web application and from templates. when the application is created I don't see startup class. no reference to Owin. VS2017 templates don't use Owin?

Comment: very vague question - give code snippet, screenshot...

Comment: You have to choose authentication type by clicking on change authentication button to get Owin and related packages with startup class.

Answer (score 4):

First, the version of Visual Studio has nothing to do with anything. However, in VS2017, you'll have three choices for a "web application" out of the box: MVC (where you later choose to include MVC, Web Api, or both), Core, and Core on the Full Framework.

The Core projects will have a `Startup.cs` class, but the MVC project will *not*, unless you indicate you want Individual Authentication. In that case, a `Startup.cs` file will be added for the purposes of Identity, but the MVC website, itself, will not be affected or controlled by that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Owin Project with Visual Studio 2017 by going to

1 . Create new project with ASP.NET (.Net Framework)
2. Select Single Page Application Template

here you go - > new owin project created